# how to apply validation on dialog form using jquery validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

i m trying to open a dialog on click of a button and opened dialog contains a login form including username and password and signin button.here is my code of html to open a dialog:
HTML CODE:

```
<body>
<div data-role="page">
 <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
 <h3>PRAYERS APP</h3>
 </div>
<div data-role="content">
   <div class="center-wrapper">
      <a href="#login_box"  id="showdialog" data-transition="pop" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-theme="e">USER LOGIN AREA</a>
   </div>

</div>
 </div>


<div data-role="dialog" id="login_box" class="login-popup" data-dismissible="false">

<a href="#" id="closeBtn" class="ui-btn-right" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext">close btn</a>  

 <div data-role="content">
    <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
            <form name="login" id="formlogin" method="get" action="" accept-charset="utf-8">

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="username">USER NAME:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="usrname" placeholder="your name"/><br/>
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="password">PASSWORD:</label><br/>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="usrpswd" placeholder="please enter your password"/><br/>
                </div>

                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                 <div class="ui-block-a">
                 <a href="#" id="signinbtn" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" style="text-align:center; float:right;">SIGN  IN</a></div>
                </fieldset>

                </form>
                    </div>
                      </div>
                       </div>
<!--  -----login page   end------------------->                        
</body>
```

one more problem when i click on "user login area button" its showing me dialog on another page while i want to open a dialog on same page:
 JS CODE TO APPLY FADEIN AND FADEOUT:

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
 {
<!-- ///////////////////////////////login dialog and its validation start//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////--> 

    var loginBox;
          $('#showdialog').click(function()
         {
            loginBox = $(this).attr('href'); 
            //Fade in the Popup and add close button
            $(loginBox).fadeIn(250);
            //Set the center alignment padding + border
            var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2;
            var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2;

            $(loginBox).css({
                'margin-top': -popMargTop,
                'margin-left': -popMargLeft
                });
            $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
            $('#mask').fadeIn(250);

            return false;
         });

        // When clicking on the close button  or the mask layer the popup closed
         $('#closeBtn, #mask').live('click',function()
          {
             $('#mask, .login-popup').fadeOut(250,function()
                {
                 $('#mask').remove(); 
                });
             return false;
          });
   });
</script>
</head>
```

now geting problem to apply validation on textbox of opened dialog for that reason i m using this code but its not working:i m applying this code in script tag

```
$('#login_box').dialog(
    {
    open: function(event,ui)
    {
    $('#formlogin').validate()
    {
    rules:
    {
    username:
        {required: true,
        minlength: 4
        },
        }
    password:
      {required: true,
      minlength: 8
      }
    },
     messages:
     {
     username: 
     {required:"pls enter user name",
     minlength: $.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required!"),
     }
    password:
     {
     required:"pls enter password",
     minlength: $.format("password should be atleast {0} characters")
    }

    }
    } 
    }
    });
```

moreover Signin button of dialog  is not clickable and failed to fire this function:

```
  $('#signinbtn').on('click',function()
            {
                alert("eerer");
                doLogin();


            });
```

i want such type of validation here is fiddle:
        [formvalidation](http://jsfiddle.net/erum/Ztn2a/) 
i have already applied all jquery plugins in  my project:

Comment: Too much information can you generalize this?

Comment: This is a job for @Sparky.

Comment: i just want to apply validation on dialog FORM. have applied "fade in " and "fade out" functions on dialog but unfortunately its open dialog on another page and its background is black. furthermore just let me know how to apply validation on forms (inside of dialog) and apply click function of any dialog button?

Comment: i m not using any jquery plugin for dialog its just my own efforts what i have applied here for dialog

Comment: `.validate()` is the method for _initializing_ the plugin on the form.  Move it up one level so it's immediately inside your DOM ready handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.validate()` is the method for *initializing* the plugin on the form. Move it up one level so it's immediately inside your DOM ready handler.

You also have lots of syntax errors inside your `.validate()` code.  Proper indentation & formatting would help you easily see them...

```
$('#formlogin').validate() { // <-- should be .validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4
        },
    } // <-- extra } puts password outside of rules
    password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 8
    }
},
messages: {
    username: {
        required: "pls enter user name",
        minlength: $.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required!"), // <-- extra comma
    } // <-- missing a comma
    password: {
        required: "pls enter password",
        minlength: $.format("password should be atleast {0} characters")
    }

}
} // <-- should be a });
```

This one is properly formatted...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#formlogin').validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            }
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "pls enter user name",
                minlength: $.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required!")
            },
            password: {
                required: "pls enter password",
                minlength: $.format("password should be atleast {0} characters")
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Simple DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/qzdyk/**

I added a `submit` button to your `form` for the demo.  The plugin will automatically capture and handle the `click` event of a `<input type="submit" />` and a `<button>click</button>`.